# How do i add event handlers to checkboxes in a listview checkbox cell?

Tags: java, user-interface, checkbox, event-handling, javafx

I am creating a list of cards that users can select from to start a game. Users select their cards by a checkbox next to the card name, and they are only allowed to select 10 cards. I want to be able to limit the number of checkboxes that can be selected by having an event handler get called when a checkbox is clicked and determine whether the checkbox is allowed to be clicked or not. How can i add an event handler to every checkbox to do this? If there is a better way, i am definitely open to suggestions. Here is my code where i setup the listview and the checkbox callback:

```
ListView<Card> cards;
Callback<Card, ObservableValue<Boolean>> checkBoxCallback = new Callback<Card, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public BooleanProperty call(Card card) {
            return card.selectedProperty();
        }
    };

    StringConverter<Card> cardToStringConverter = new StringConverter<Card>() {
        @Override
        public Card fromString(String card) {
            try {
                return CardFactory.createCard(card);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(Card card) {
            return card.toString();
        }

    };

    Callback<ListView<Card>, ListCell<Card>> listViewCallback = CheckBoxListCell.forListView(checkBoxCallback, cardToStringConverter);
    cards.setCellFactory(listViewCallback);
    cards.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Card>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Card> obsValue,
                Card oldValue, Card newValue) {
            cardImageView.setImage(newValue.getCardImage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: y cant you use a static global variable which counts the cards checked also you could have a check that the count variable is less than 10..?? it would be my choice

Comment: how would i know when a checkbox is clicked without an event handler attached to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getSelectedProperty `Callback` parameter of `CheckBoxListCell.forListView()` is bound bidirectionally,

> (meaning that the CheckBox in the cell will set/unset this property
>   based on user interactions, and the CheckBox will reflect the state of
>   the ObservableValue, if it changes externally).

Thereby adding a change listener to the `Card.selectedProperty()` may be more accurate, covering the external modification by both checkBoxes and other controls/setters.

```
final IntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
Text text = new Text("-");
// Bind count to text, to show on scene.
text.textProperty().bind(count.asString());

ChangeListener listener = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        count.set(count.get() + (newValue ? 1 : -1));
        if (count.get() >= 10) {
            System.out.println("exceeded max limit");
            // Revert selection
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((BooleanProperty) observable).set(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
for (final Card card : cards.getItems()) {
    card.selectedProperty().addListener(listener);
}
```

At the end of the user work, remove the listeners.

```
for (final Card card : cards.getItems()) {
    card.selectedProperty().removeListener(listener);
}
```

Alternatively, if you strictly want to add listeners to checkboxes only, you can create custom ListCell having checkboxes internally and set a ListView.cellFactory().

Comment: The javafx api for the ChangeListener states, "In general is is considered bad practice to modify the observed value in this method." -http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html Is there another way around editing the observable value, or is this the best option?

Comment: @jwill, the value is not being changed in the method. It is changing in a new Runnable, later after exiting the method. The code in the Runnable triggers another changelistener event.